# Mid span weight capacity

Tags: wood, engineering

What is the mid-span (center of wood board) load bearing capacity of one 2”x12”x10’ setting on edge. I will be mounting a 1 ton chain hoist by a 2”x36” tow hook strap rated up to 3,300 lbs dead load weight capacity that will be wrapped around the center of the 2”x12”x10’.  I have viewed some beam calculations ratings showing maximum center load of 7,500 lbs. Can someone please help verify?  It is an existing Morton type of metal structure that has two 10’x10’ garage doors that I will attach the chain hoist to one of the 2”x12”x10’ headers.

Comment: is this 2x12 a part of an existing structure, or is this something that you are building?

Comment: Please [merge your guest and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!